# in vb.net datagrideview filter by Combobox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dv As DataView


    dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
   

    dv = New DataView(dt, "[Game Name]='DERA'", "[Game Name] desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
End Sub
```

this is my code is working , But I need this code filter by combobox1 as like next code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim dv As DataView


    dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
   

    dv = New DataView(dt, "[Game Name]" = ComboBox2.SelectedItem, "[Game Name] desc", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
End Sub
```

Comment: This site provides you with a preview of your question for a reason. Please look at it and don't submit your question if the formatting is a mess. If you'd like us to volunteer our time to help you, please take the time to help us by posting clear questions that contain all the relevant information.

Comment: What you're doing is very wrong. You don't change the `DataSource` of the grid. If you have bound a `DataTable` to your grid then you can simply set its `DefaultView.RowFilter` property. Better, though, to bind your `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` (which you would add in the designer) and bind that to the grid. You then simply set the `Filter` property of that `BindingSource`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.